# Pipe input/output to a process

Tags: c, windows, pipe, stdout, stdin

I have some difficulties getting my pipes work. I have the following code:

```
/* Set security attributes */
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

if (CreatePipe(&Rread, &Rwrite, &sa, 0) == 0 || SetHandleInformation(Rread, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) == 0 || CreatePipe(&Wread, &Wwrite, &sa, 0) == 0 || SetHandleInformation(Wwrite, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) == 0)
{
    /* Error */
}


/* Set process information */
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
si.hStdOutput = Rwrite;
si.hStdError = Rwrite;


if (CreateProcess(NULL, argsCasted->cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) == 0)
{
    /* Error */
}


for (;;)
{
    PeekNamedPipe(Rread, NULL, 0, &a, NULL, NULL);

    if (a > 0)
    {
        /* Write output somewhere... */
    }

    if (a == 0 && GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &c) != 0 && c != STILL_ACTIVE) break;

    Sleep(50);
}


    /* CloseHandles... */

    /* Free stuff... */
```

Now when I add `si.hStdInput = Wread;` (so that I can send input to the process), `PeekNamedPipe()` blocks.

I simplified the code a lot because it is part of a large multi-threaded application, which is too large to post here. If anyone needs more details from me to solve this problem, please post it here and I'll add the requested details.

Thanks in advance
Jori.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PeekNamedPipe` will block if there is no data in the pipe to read. You will have to make use of asynchronous/non-blocking I/O.

Refer : [asynchronous IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes I know that, but it only happens when I add: si.hStdInput = Wread;? Why that?

Comment: @Jori: the most likely reason is that the external program behaves differently depending on whether it has a valid standard input handle or not.  How are you initializing `si`?

Comment: `STARTUPINFO si = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);`

Comment: I'm not sure offhand what is supposed to happen if you set hStdInput to NULL when STARTF_USESTDHANDLES is defined, but I suspect you're confusing the subprocess by doing so.  Anyway, I think the bottom line is that PeekNamedPipe is unreliable, so you shouldn't use it - the docs say that sometimes it will block and sometimes it won't, but don't properly describe the conditions under which blocking will or won't occur.